# Angular2 Html views with systemJS and text plugin, 'exports.translate' is undefined

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

I know this is an older discussion, but i came across this problem while using angular2 with systemjs. The only things i have as meta are as follows:

```
System.config({
    'defaultJSExtensions': true,
     baseURL: '/js',
     map: {
         text: '/js/angular2/text.js'
     }
}
```

I use text plugin to load my html views and they do load properly, however I still get this error mentioned in followings, why is that?

"text.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined(anonymous function)"

The whole `text.js` file is pretty straight forward:

```
(function(System, SystemJS) {(function(require, exports, module, __filename, __dirname, global, GLOBAL) {/*
Text plugin
*/
exports.translate = function(load) {
  return 'module.exports = "' + load.source
    .replace(/(["\\])/g, '\\$1')
    .replace(/[\f]/g, "\\f")
    .replace(/[\b]/g, "\\b")
    .replace(/[\n]/g, "\\n")
    .replace(/[\t]/g, "\\t")
    .replace(/[\r]/g, "\\r")
    .replace(/[\u2028]/g, "\\u2028")
    .replace(/[\u2029]/g, "\\u2029")
  + '";';
}
}).apply(__cjsWrapper.exports, __cjsWrapper.args);
})(System, System);
```

Line 4, is indeed says `exports.translate`. I couldn't find an option for `text.js` to specify i'm not using NodeJS, so how would I get around this issue?

Comment: Do you want to implement your module with commonjs or systemjs apis?

Comment: Angular2 is SystemJS with register format. However, Angular2's source is written in `register` format itself. So yes i'm trying to use SystemJS apis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens if the request for `text.js` was sent via browser rather than `SystemJS`. It has to be requested and downloaded via `SystemJS`. Your dev bundling should be setup properly to accommodate for this.

Although as @Thierry Themplier has mentioned, you can leave it as is and create package configurations for your folders to specify the default `.js` extensions and `.html` or any other extensions that you need. In my case this will be a maintenance nightmare with deep folder hierarchies and a bad dependency over where the source files are located.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the SystemJS APIs, I would try the following to register your module:

```
System.register('mymodule', [ ], function(exports, context) {
  exports.translate = function(load) {
    return 'module.exports = "' + load.source
      .replace(/(["\\])/g, '\\$1')
      .replace(/[\f]/g, "\\f")
      .replace(/[\b]/g, "\\b")
      .replace(/[\n]/g, "\\n")
      .replace(/[\t]/g, "\\t")
      .replace(/[\r]/g, "\\r")
      .replace(/[\u2028]/g, "\\u2028")
      .replace(/[\u2029]/g, "\\u2029")
    + '";';
  };
});
```

This way you don't need to add the `text.js` in a `map` but directly include using the `<script>` tag:

```
<script src="text.js"></script>
```

You can then import your module this way:

```
import {translate} from 'mymodule';
```

**Edit**

With an anonymous module:

```
System.register([ ], function(exports, context) {
  exports.translate = function(load) {
    return 'module.exports = "' + load.source
      .replace(/(["\\])/g, '\\$1')
      .replace(/[\f]/g, "\\f")
      .replace(/[\b]/g, "\\b")
      .replace(/[\n]/g, "\\n")
      .replace(/[\t]/g, "\\t")
      .replace(/[\r]/g, "\\r")
      .replace(/[\u2028]/g, "\\u2028")
      .replace(/[\u2029]/g, "\\u2029")
    + '";';
  };
});
```

In this case, it's up to you to link the module file with a name (with the default extension or a dedicated entry in the `packages` block).

Comment: Well i solved an issue with SystemJS not adding the `.js` extension by specifying `defaultJSExtensions: true` in configs. Your approach requires package definitions to properly add extensions which will undo that fix. So now without `!text` how do you tell SystemJS to add `.js` or `.html` extension to which resource?

Comment: You could also create an aynonymous module (by removing the first parameter of the `System.register` function). In this case, it's up to you to link the module file with a name...

Comment: The main `text.js` came from NPM. I like to keep it as default if possible (which it was) so i can upgrade or hand the code to my colleagues and they would restore packages. It works as is, given someone reads this whole page.